# Не удается наладить процедуры и их вызов Pascal

Tags: функции, pascal, freepascal

```
const
    n=5;
    m=11;
type
    q=array [1..n,1..m] of char;
var

path_in,path_out:string;
    mas:q;
    c:char;
    s,k,max,ii,jj:integer;

procedure sort(var mas1: q; n, m: integer);
var
  ii, j, sort, k: integer;
  c: char;
begin
  for sort := 1 to 3 do
    for ii := 1 to n - 1 do
    begin
      j := 8;
      while (mas[ii, j] = mas1[ii + 1, j]) and (j <= m) do
        j := j + 1;
      writeln(mas1[ii, j]);
      if (mas1[ii, j] > mas[ii + 1, j]) and (j <= m) then
        for k := 1 to m do
        begin
          c := mas1[ii, k];
          mas1[ii, k] := mas1[ii + 1, k];
          mas1[ii + 1, k] := c;
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure perewrite(path_out: string; var mas1: q; var n, m: integer);
var
  max, k: integer;
  file_txt: Text;
begin
  Assign(file_txt, path_out);
  reset(file_txt);
  rewrite(file_txt);
  for max := n downto n - 2 do
  begin
    for k := 1 to m do
    begin
      Write(mas1[max, k]);
      Write(file_txt, mas1[max, k]);
    end;
    writeln(file_txt);
  end;
  Close(file_txt);
end;

{end-procedure perewrite}
begin
  writeln('ishodnii file:');
  path_in := 'input.txt';
  Open(path_in, mas1);

  path_out := 'output.txt';
  perewrite(path_out, mas1);

  for ii := 1 to n do
  begin
    for jj := 1 to m do
      Write(mas1[ii, jj]);
    writeln;
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая ошибка: вы в процедуре open читаете массив mas1, передаваемый по значению, т.е. после завершения процедуры он уничтожится, лучше создайте глобальный массив, там же, где и mas:q (т.е. до объявления процедур)
и не передавайте его, а сразу используйте

Тоже самое и в процедуре perewrite, уберите массив из параметров, в паскале все передаётся через значение(а это очень плохо), и уменьшите табуляцию(максимум 2 таба для вложенного оператора), т.к. код нечитаем

Comment: не уничтожится. в остальном верно.

Comment: @Sleepless
    str.pas(77,1) Error: Wrong number of parameters specified for call to "open"
вот такие ошибки на вызов процедур.

    path_in:='input.txt';
    open(path_in ,mas);
    
    path_out:='output.txt';
    perewrite(path_out,mas);


убрал из процедур массив остался использоваться единственный глобальный

Comment: Вы убрали массив из параметров, теперь не передавайте при вызове, Вот так: open(path_in);